# iOS (objective C) version of ualarm()

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface

I am looking for an Objective-C function to call a function to update the UI at a specified interval (between 2 and 5 seconds). Something that can be used (roughly) like this pseudocode:

```
array[String];   // already populated

function1(){
    if (array.hasMoreElements()){
        call function2() in x seconds;
    }
}

void function2(){
    update gui with next string in the array;
    function1();
}
```

I simply can't use sleep() for x seconds, because the GUI will become unresponsive; and I can't create a new thread to update the GUI because the iOS UI elements are not thread safe.

I have researched ualarm(), but it is old and very crude, and someone told me that there is a similar utility in the iOS library; however I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [NSTimer](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html&ei=1Ih3TtmBEKGm0QXku6CYCA&usg=AFQjCNHfssrHuGgMrRf_guSy45gLWQhJVQ&sig2=kPXI_r8anuqYkvbOClDR3w). This API fits perfectly what you want to do.

You can simply define a method like

```
-(void)updateUI {
     //update interface 
}
```

then do something like

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(updateUI) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This way the timer will continue call the method you set. Check the reference to see how to stop or invalidate the timer.

Comment: This definitely works, but timers have some sharp corners around ownership and invalidation. They're best-suited for long-running, repeated specific interval tasks. For general delays and draining short queues, I generally stick with the `performSelector` stuff because it's a lot harder to get wrong.

Comment: Yes, probably timers are more delicate than a simple call to `performSelector`, but the update of the UI at a "specified interval" (as the OP said) is a "long-running, repeated specific interval" task (as you said). I perfectly agree that, for a general delay, a call to `performSelector` is far simpler, but in this case I think `NSTimer`s better fit the problem

Answer (score 5):

You're talking about Obj-C but writing something like C pseudocode. If you're really writing normal Obj-C, the `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` is the general family you want that drops in here. (You can use "blocks" on iOS 4.x and above). For example in your use case:

```
- (void)displayNextString
{
    if ([strings count] > 0) {
        [self updateUIwithString:[strings objectAtIndex:0]];
        [strings removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(displayNextString) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    }
}
```